# Using strcmp in an if statement

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I am fairly new to C, and I am trying to understand using strings and `strcmp` to compare two strings in an `if` statement.

My goal is to be able to run a different function depending on what the user has inputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void gasbill();
void electricitybill();

int main()
{
  char input[20];
  const char gasCheck[4] = "gas";
  const char electricityCheck[13] = "electricity";

  printf("Your bills explained!\n\n");
  printf("In this application I will go through your gas and electricty bills.\n");
  printf("I will explain how each of the billing payments work, \nand the calculations that go on,\n");
  printf("to create your bill.\n\n");
  printf("Please choose a bill to get started with:\n- gas\n- electricity\n\n");
  fgets(input, 20, stdin);

  if (strcmp (input, gasCheck)== 0){
    printf("\nPreparing to run Gas bill!\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    system("cls");
    gasbill();
    system("PAUSE");
  }
  else if (strcmp (input, electricityCheck)== 0){
    printf("\nPreparing to run Electricity bill!\n\n");
    system("cls");
    electricitybill();
    system("PAUSE");}
  else {
    printf("\nError exiting...\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
  }

  return 0;
}

void gasbill()
{
  float balanceBroughtForward, gasThisQuarter, subTotalPerQuarter;
  char poundSign = 156;

  printf("******Your gas bill, explained!******\n\n\n");
  printf("Hello, and welcome to your gas bill, explained. Let's get started.\n");
  printf("Please enter the balance brought forward from your previous statement: \n\n%c", poundSign);
  scanf("%f", &balanceBroughtForward);
  printf("\nHow this works:\n- The money that you did not pay last quarter for your gas bill\nhas been added to this quarterly payment\n\n");
  printf("\nNext let's add this to the amount of gas you have spent this quarter. \n(how much gas have you used so far in this billing period?)");
  printf(": %c", poundSign);
  scanf("%f", &gasThisQuarter);
  printf("\n\nNow what? The two values that you have entered\n(balance brought forward 
  and gas spent this quarter)\nare added together, %c%3.2f + %c%3.2f\n", poundSign, 
  balanceBroughtForward, poundSign, gasThisQuarter);
  subTotalPerQuarter = (balanceBroughtForward + gasThisQuarter);
  printf("This is"); 
}

void electricitybill()
{
  printf("Empty");
  system("PAUSE");   
}
```

When ever it runs the if statement it always executes the gasBill function and not the electricityBill function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting null at the end of your const char's manually.  That might fix the discrepency.

Comment: Using a slightly less bloated version, serving as an example, the code  above worked for me. I get gas, electricity or error, depending on what I write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) will return a string which ends with a newline (`\n`).  From its documentation

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str
>   until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the
>   end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

You could either test for a trailing newline and strip it off

```
fgets(input, 20, stdin);
size_t len = strlen(input);
if (input[len-1] == '\n') {
    input[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

or read user input using [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) instead.

```
scanf("%19s", input);
```

As an aside

```
const char gasCheck[4] = "gas";
const char electricityCheck[13] = "electricity";
```

could be declared slightly more easily and safely as

```
const char *gasCheck = "gas";
const char *electricityCheck = "electricity";
```

(This form saves copying the string literals into stack variables.  More importantly, it removes a potential source of bugs if you hard-code too small a length for the arrays.)

Comment: Altought, i would avoid using scanf, since it can lead to security problem and bug, since it can write more than size of the string.

Comment: Hmmm... +1 for pointing out `fgets()`, -1 for using the notorious `scanf()` for reading user input. Whitespaces in the user input could give you something different than expected, for example...

Comment: @user1115057 A format string of `"%19s"` will read at most 19 chars (plus null terminator) so is guaranteed not to write beyond the end of `input`

Comment: @simonc So after messing with your different suggestions, I had no luck and decided to return to how it initially was. I can still run the error and the gasbill but the electricity won't work. So I took out the section of the if statement for the gasbill, so when I type "gas" I get the error; as expected but the electricity still won't run it also returns error. Edit: I changed the const chars to pointers (I think they are called) like you suggested, thank you.

Comment: But using %19s is not safe, since we relly on the parsing ability of the function. Its more safe to use a safe function than using an unsafe function and trying to give him some argument that could make it more safe. Also, since scanf need to parse thing out, it will use more resource.

Comment: Edit: Tried one more combination I forgot. Using scanf("%19s", &input); worked Thank you for the help all.

Comment: @user1115057 Just in case this isn't a troll, which function's parsing ability are you worried about?  If you're worried about buggy standard libraries that implement `scanf` incorrectly, the same risks would apply when using `fgets` or whatever "safe" alternative you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

fgets() read characters from stdin until a newline is seen or an EOF, if newline was seen, it would be stored in the array.Anyway, fgets() appends a null character to the array.

so if you want end your input by newline, my  minor alteration is here, change this

```
const char gasCheck[4] = "gas";
const char electricityCheck[13] = "electricity";
```

to

```
const char gasCheck[5] = "gas\n";
const char electricityCheck[14] = "electricity\n";
```